# C#, EF: Create Linq query that compares on two properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

So I've got a conundrum that I can't think my way out of.  Basically,  I have a Book object with two properties, Title and ISBN.  What I want to say is, from this list of Books, check the database for a Book that has a matching combination.

Naive code would look like so:

```
foreach( var book in BookList )
{ 
   var matchingBook = 
        context.BookSet.Where( n => n.ISBN.Equals(book.ISBN ) 
           && n.Title.Equals(book.Title)).FirstOrDefault();

   if( matchingBook )
   ....
}
```

Clearly, this is a sub-optimal solution, but I don't know how to get around this other than to iterate over the books, create a composite key (ISBN + "-" + Title) and then send that to the DB, but that's feels a little sloppy because indexes can't be used.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to have the BookId in your BookList, then you can simply get your book from the context with *find(bookId)*.

Comment: And if you want just optimize query the solution is  context.BookSet.FirstOrDefault( n => n.ISBN == book.ISBN && n.Title == book.Title);

Answer (score 0):

Just use join to get the matching data

```
var matchingBook =from bkSet in context.BookSet join bkList in BookList on bkSet.Title equals bkList.Title
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement is equality check, solution is rather simple, you can create a keywords list to check and query like,

```
var keywords = bookList.Select(x => x.ISBN + x.Name);
var filteredBooks = context.Books.Where(x => keywords.Contains(x.ISBN + x.Name));
//other filters on filteredBooks if any goes here
var result= filteredBooks.ToList();
```

this will create an `in` clause in sql which will look something similar to,

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ISBN] AS [ISBN], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM [dbo].[Books] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[ISBN] + [Extent1].[Name] IN 
         (N'123-45Test 2', N'55656-78Test 3', 
          N'345345-67Test 4', N'5656-767Test 5')) 
    AND ([Extent1].[ISBN] + [Extent1].[Name] IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Ok, seems like you already considered this idea, sorry I overlooked that part of your question, but this is the most practical if you go through linq approach. Give it a go and see if execution plan used is any good

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible without resorting to a table valued function that takes the input titles and ISBNs as a table valued parameter. You might consider going with the concatenation approach as you suggested. If you need an index to get acceptable performance, you can add the composite key as a persisted computed column and index on that.